# Farm Sink Drain Installation

Tags: water, drain, sink

I recently had a farm sink installed in my kitchen. I noticed that the drain seems to sit slightly above the curve of the drain hole. A little bit of water also pools around the drain when the sink is used. Is this normal or does the drain need to be reinstalled to sit lower? I asked Kohler support and they said it looks like it was installed correctly, and they said it could appear slightly raised due to the plumbers puddy underneath. Most sinks I’ve seen, the drain sits below the curve of the drain hole though.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look at  the  strainer from the underside of the sink you should see a  rubber gasket as Jimmy Fix-it explained. If you don't my guess is it was incorrectly installed on the top side. Post a picture from underneath if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

That does **not** appear to be correctly installed, it should lie flush with or below the sink surface.

These strainer assemblies commonly come with 2 ring-shaped washers; one rubber and one hard plastic or fiber. *Both* should be placed on the underside of the sink between the strainer mounting hardware and bottom sink surface. Neither are for "sealing" purposes. The rubber one is a cushion and the plastic/fiber one is a friction ring.

Make sure that there is no gasket of any sort between the upper strainer lip and the sink (it sure looks like there is...). The only thing between the strainer lip and the sink should be plumber's putty, and any excess putty squeezes out when the strainer is tightened (until flush with or below the sink surface) to the sink.

The only other possibilities are that the strainer has not been tightened completely down, or the sink (or strainer) is defective.